# Plugin download link

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, automatic-updates

I am facing this problem on my plugin.

The update link is something like that:

```
https://acpt.io/wp-json/api/v1/plugin/download?license=xxxxx&user_id=yyyyy
```

(I need those two parameters for checking user license)

If I call this link from any browser or via CURL it works fine.

But, when I try to update the plugin from the Update plugin page (`/wp-admin/update-core.php`) I got this error:

```
An error occurred while updating ACPT: Download failed. Service Unavailable
```

There is nothing on the logs :(

This is the complete code:

```php
class ACPT_Updater 
{
    // ... other code

    /**
     * init the plugin
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', [ $this, 'modifyTransient' ], 10, 1 );
        add_filter( 'plugins_api', [ $this, 'pluginPopup' ], 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'upgrader_post_install', [ $this, 'afterInstall' ], 10, 3 );
    }

    /**
     * @param $transient
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function modifyTransient( $transient )
    {
        if( property_exists( $transient, 'checked') ) {
            if( $checked = $transient->checked ) {

                $pluginInfo = $this->getPluginInfo();

                if(is_array($pluginInfo) and isset($pluginInfo['version'])){
                    $version = $pluginInfo['version'];
                    $version = str_replace(['v.', 'v'], '', $version);

                    $outOfDate = version_compare( $version, $this->plugin["Version"], 'gt' );
                    if( $outOfDate ) {
                        $newFiles = LicenseApi::downloadLink();
                        $slug = current( explode('/', $this->basename ) );

                        $plugin = [
                            'url' => $this->plugin["PluginURI"],
                            'slug' => $slug,
                            'package' => $newFiles,
                            'new_version' => $version
                        ];

                        $transient->response[ $this->basename ] = (object) $plugin;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $transient;
    }

    /**
     * @param $result
     * @param $action
     * @param $args
     *
     * @return object
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function pluginPopup( $result, $action, $args )
    {
        if( ACPT_License_Manager::isLicenseValid() and ! empty( $args->slug ) ) {
            if( $args->slug == current( explode( '/' , $this->basename ) ) ) {

                $pluginInfo = $this->getPluginInfo();
                $version = $pluginInfo['version'];
                $version = str_replace(['v.', 'v'], '', $version);
                $downloadLink = LicenseApi::downloadLink();
                $updates = '<div><h3>ACPT v'.$version.'</h3><p>If you can\'t automatically update the plugin, you can download it here and manually load it on your website.</p> <a href="'
                        .$downloadLink.'">Download here</a></div>';

                $plugin = [
                    'name'              => $this->plugin["Name"],
                    'slug'              => $this->basename,
                    'version'           => $version,
                    'author'            => $this->plugin["AuthorName"],
                    'author_profile'    => $this->plugin["AuthorURI"],
                    'last_updated'      => $pluginInfo['published_at'],
                    'homepage'          => $this->plugin["PluginURI"],
                    'short_description' => $this->plugin["Description"],
                    'sections'          => [
                        'Description'   => $this->plugin["Description"],
                        'Updates'       => $updates,
                    ],
                    'download_link'     => $downloadLink
                ];

                return (object)$plugin;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $response
     * @param $hook_extra
     * @param $result
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterInstall( $response, $hook_extra, $result )
    {
        global $wp_filesystem;

        $install_directory = plugin_dir_path( $this->file );
        $wp_filesystem->move( $result['destination'], $install_directory );
        $result['destination'] = $install_directory;

        if ( $this->active ) {
            activate_plugin( $this->basename );
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

The function `LicenseApi::downloadLink();` is responsabile to create the download link above reported.

Am I missing something? Maybe the query string structure in the url is not working for some reasons?

Thanks in advance to all of you!

Comment: are you the author of ACPT? There is no code in your question showing how you have implemented the updater, just a URL, and no information on how you're retrieving the error message

Comment: @TomJNowell I added the complete code. I got the error on /wp-admin/update-core.php page and also in the standard plugins page. Thank you!

Comment: _are you the author of ACPT?_ What does the update URL do? Is it a file download? Or a webpage? What debugging steps have you taken to inspect the HTTP request response directly?

Comment: Hi! Yes I am the author of ACPT plugin. The URL downloads the zip of current plugin version. I tried with no success to debug the problem, since the log doesn't write anything and even with debug mode set to true no errors are displayed, except for the one I pasted above. @TomJNowell

Comment: even with query monitor installed? Normally plugins like that or debug toolbar will show the HTTP requests made during a WP request, their timings, and the responses. Without that kind of information we don't know what the return value of `LicenseApi::downloadLink()` is and wether it's valid or works as expected either

Comment: @TomJNowell please see below

Comment: Delete that immediately! You should use the edit link to edit your question if you have more/new info, don't post updates as solutions to your question!! People will think you have found your solution.